GPU performance worse than CPU performance on YOLO inferences
I am using the YoloDotNet NuGet package to test the performance of YOLO models. I'm doing this testing for my degree thesis. However, I have encountered an issue where the GPU performance is significantly worse than the CPU performance.

The problem is that the performance for the first 50/60 inferences are really good(like 20ms) and then they start to get worst until the time gets stable around 70/75ms per image. I don't get why the performance gets worst in that way.

Environment:

YoloDotNet version: v2.0
CPU: AMD ryzen 7 7800X3D
GPU: 4070 super
CUDA/cuDNN version: cuda 11.8 and cudnn 8.9.7
.NET version: 8

Steps to reproduce:
var sw = new Stopwatch();
for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    var file = $@"C:\Users\Utente\Documents\assets\images\input\frame_{i}.jpg";

    using var image = SKImage.FromEncodedData(file);
    sw.Restart();
    var results = yolo.RunObjectDetection(image, confidence: 0.25, iou: 0.7);
    sw.Stop();
    image.Draw(results);

    image.Save(file.Replace("input", $"output_{yolo_version}{version}_{target}").Replace(".jpg", $"_detect_{yolo_version}{version}_{target}.jpg"),
        SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg);
    times.Add(sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine($"Time taken for image {i}: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds:F2} ms");

This is the way I'm taking the time measure for the detections.
To load the model i use this setup in the GPU case
yolo = new Yolo(new YoloOptions
{
    OnnxModel = @$"C:\Users\Utente\Documents\assets\model\yolov{yolo_version}{version}_{target}.onnx",
    ModelType = ModelType.ObjectDetection,  // Model type
    Cuda = true,                           // Use CPU or CUDA for GPU accelerated inference. Default = true
    GpuId = 0,                               // Select Gpu by id. Default = 0
    PrimeGpu = true,                       // Pre-allocate GPU before first. Default = false
});
Console.WriteLine(yolo.OnnxModel.ModelType);
Console.WriteLine($"Using GPU for version {yolo_version}{version}");

Performance Metrics using yolov8:
CPU Inference Time: 
Total time taken for version m: 25693 ms

Average time per image for version m: 51.25 ms

GPU Inference Time: 
Total time taken for version m: 34459.73 ms

Average time per image for version m: 69.74 ms

I would like to post graphs about the times but I do not have enough reputation
The issue presents its self for different sizes of the model. I have printed only the size m for ease of visualization.
Expected behavior is that the inference using the GPU should be faster than inference using the CPU.
But the performance is not improving using the GPU.

Unless I’m misunderstanding your results, using the GPU is faster than the CPU, with a lower ‘time per image’?

My bad, I have written the measurment wrong. Now its correct the CPU is faster than the GPU doing the inference

those are batches of size 1... you should take an intro course to gpu programming. you must learn about this, or else be forever surprised by it not being "just faster".

@ChristophRackwitz I get what you are saying but here the problem is that the performance for the first 50/60 inferences are really good(like 20ms) and then they start to get worst until the time gets stable around 70/75ms per image.
I don't get why the performance gets worst in that way.
If you have suggestion in what should i look on I will be more than happy to take a look!

that's news. please [edit] your question to clarify the timing behavior you just described. -- are you sure the sw thingy measures only from restart to stop? if any of the image file saving affects the timing... perhaps just disable that piece and check again. apart from that, IDK why it would run faster initially. maybe memory allocation pressure. you ARE doing 1-size batches, and IDK what ultralyics code does in the background to manage memory, or not.

@ChristophRackwitz just posted the solution to my problem, thank you for your suggestion!

Hi huge thanks to @ChristophRackwitz that suggested to disable this piece of the code
image.Draw(results);

    image.Save(file.Replace("input", $"output_{yolo_version}{version}_{target}").Replace(".jpg", $"_detect_{yolo_version}{version}_{target}.jpg"),
        SKEncodedImageFormat.Jpeg);

After disabling this part the timings per detection started to be on point.
I'm not really sure why but my suspect is that the Skiasharp for all the I/O
operations generated a huge use of memory slowing down the image passing from the CPU to the GPU.
This is the code that I have written to have as much things ready and to not do nothing else than detections in the loop.
I have also forced the disposal of the image after the loop to be sure to have freed the memory for the next model inference.
// Load all images into memory
for (var i = 1; i < 500; i++)
{
    string file = $@"C:\Users\Eduard\Documents\assets\images\input\frame_{i}.jpg";
    using var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    var image = SKImage.FromEncodedData(stream);
    images.Add(i, image);
}

// Run inference on in-memory images
foreach (var kvp in images)
{
    int i = kvp.Key;

    sw.Restart();
    var results = yolo.RunObjectDetection(kvp.Value, confidence: 0.25, iou: 0.7);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Time taken for image {i}: {sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds:F2} ms");
    rawResults.Add((i, results, sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds));
}

// Dispose of images to free memory
foreach (var kvp in images)
{
    kvp.Value.Dispose();
}

// Process results outside the loop
foreach (var rawResult in rawResults)
{
    int imageIndex = rawResult.imageIndex;
    var results = rawResult.results;
    double elapsedMilliseconds = rawResult.elapsedMilliseconds;

    times.Add(elapsedMilliseconds);

    if (results.Count > 0)
    {
        var labels = new List<string>();
        var confidences = new List<double>();
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            labels.Add(result.Label.Name.ToString());
            confidences.Add(result.Confidence);
        }
        detections.Add((
           imageIndex,
           labels,
           confidences
         ));
    }
}

Now the times for the YOLOv8 size m are

Total time of execution 11825.34ms
And an average time per image of 23.70ms

